# CSS and JS files failed to load - when Angular App copied into webapps folder of Tomcat 6

Tags: angularjs, tomcat

Hope someone can help me here

I am trying to host the angular application using Tomcat 6.0. Now the problem is when hit the index.html not all the CSS and JS files loading properly.Especially bootstrap.css and Jquery files.

But angular-min and angular-route loads properly.

Console logs says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Help me out here. Not sure what is wrong...

My html ref

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--external css-->
    <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/zabuto_calendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/js/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/lineicons/style.css">
    <link href="assets/css/table-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/form_style_7.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="angular/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
```

URL i use : http://localhost:8080/PMPortalRedesign/index.html

folder structure :
within webapps of tomcat

PMPortalRedesign\assets\css and PMPortalRedesign\assets\js

Comment: Post error stack trace ! Server is responding with 500 so May be issue is something else not with script loading.

Comment: 500-C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\PMPortalRedesign\angular\bootstrap.css (Access is denied)
message C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\PMPortalRedesign\angular\bootstrap.css (Access is denied)description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\PMPortalRedesign\angular\bootstrap.css (Access is denied) when i hit thisinbrowser http://localhost:8080/PMPortalRedesign/angular/bootstrap.css

Comment: It is showing Access is denied. Does the directory have read/write permissions. check it.